# Flux with divergence that comes out as 0

Tags: calculus, divergence-operator

I am new to calculus and I am puzzled at the following question. I will explain where my thoughts are heading, and any feedback would be really appreciated.

Find the Flux of field $(-y,x,5)$, which leaves the surface of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ below $z=4$ (with "leaving" we mean "moving away from the origin").

Naturally, I would want to use the formula $Φ=\iint_σF·\mathbf ndS=\iiint_GdivFdV$, but when I calculate the divergence of formula $(-y,x,5)$, I get $0$, which makes little sense. Could anybody shed light on why this is, where my mistake is, and how to proceed?

Many thanks!

Comment: You are right that the divergence is 0.  And so the flux is zero.  Maybe they want you to see that if you had tried to do the surface integral, it would have been rather involved, but that the volume integral of the divergence is trivial and so, in the future, you should remember all the tools you have at your disposal with these problems.  That's all I can figure.  I would triple check the problem to make sure you read it right.

Comment: @bob.sacamento why not consider posting this as an answer

Comment: @peek-a-boo  OK.  Did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, but unfortunately you've missed a crucial element. When are you supposed to use the formula with divergence to calculate the flux? The surface has to enclose a volume. In your case, the flux is leaving the sphere of radius $5$, centered at the origin, but only below $z=4$. That means only a part of the spherical shell (does not completely enclose a volume). But, like I've said, not all is lost. Let's complete the surface by adding the disk at $z=4$. Now we know that the total flux is $0$, But whatever goes out through the spherical part **MUST** be going in through the part that we added. Now the integral of the flux through the disk is trivial, since the normal is $(0,0,1)$. Then $\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf n=5$. The disk has radius $3$. The surface of the disk is then $\pi3^2$, and when you multiply with $5$ you get $45\pi$. Now all you need is to figure out the sign.

Comment: Thank you, Andrei! According to the best of my understanding, this sign should be negative. Correct?

Comment: Indeed. The flux through the disk is positive.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the divergence is 0. And so the flux is zero. Maybe they want you to see that if you had tried to do the surface integral, it would have been rather involved, but that the volume integral of the divergence is trivial and so, in the future, you should remember all the tools you have at your disposal with these problems. That's all I can figure. I would triple check the problem to make sure you read it right.

Comment: Thank you, Bob! The thing is that the following are the only answers given, amongst which I have to choose: 9π, -9π, 15π, -15π, 36π, -36π, 45π, -45π. So should I conclude there is a mistake in the book?

Comment: The surface is open, so you cannot apply the divergence theorem directly. See my answer

Comment: @Andrei  I understand the question to be such that the volume is the closed volume bounded by the sphere and the plane $z=4$.

Comment: Hi again, Bob. I had understood it just like you, and there was no indication to the contrary. However, Andrei's answer makes sense...

Comment: It "clearly" :) states that it leaves the "surface of the sphere"