# Flux for the total and individual sides of a cube

Tags: calculus, integration

I am new to calculus and would love some feedback regarding the following question:

Given is the field $\mathbf f(x,y,z)=3\mathbf i+3\mathbf j-2\mathbf k$.

Let $V$ be a cube with its extremities at points (+/-1,+/-1,+/-1). Let's refer to the four walls as $S_1,…,S_4$ and the upper and lower bases as $S_5$ and $S_6$. Every wall and every base has an external unit normal, which we will refer to as $\mathbf {n_1},…,\mathbf {n_6}$. Let $S$ be the entire surface of the cube, that is to say $S=S_1\cup S_2\cup…\cup S_6$, and $\mathbf n$ the external unit normal to $S$.

Which of the following statements is/are correct?

1. $\iint_{S_k} \mathbf f·\mathbf {n_k} ds$ = 0, for $k = 1,…,6$.
2. $\iint_{S} \mathbf f·\mathbf {n} ds$ = 0$.

My answer is that both are correct, given that the divergence comes out as 0, which therefore nullifies the result irrespective of the surface being an individual side or the entire surface of the cube.

Many thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Why do you think that this vector (independent of $x,y,z$ ) $\mathbf f(x,y,z)=3\mathbf i+3\mathbf j-2\mathbf k$ is a field?

Comment: @zoli only because it says in the text "given is the /field/..."

Comment: The divergence theorem applies to the entire surface of a volume... so clearly the second integral is $0$, but I fail to understand how you conclude that the first integral is $0$ for each $k$. All we know is that they sum to $0$. If you actually do the integrals for the first 6, you might find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same principle as in [Flux with divergence that comes out as 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246747). The flux through each piece of surface can be some finite number, but from the divergence theorem you get the total flux (sum of the fluxes through each side) is zero. For example , the surface at $z=1$ has the normal vector $1\mathbf k$, so the flux through $S_6$ is $\iint_{S_5} (-2)ds=-8$. Similarly, you can show that the flux through $S_6$ is $+8$. If you add the two, you get $0$. You can repeat the process for the sides.